# Distributing graphs across several machines in Distributed Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently working on a project using Distributed Tensorflow. My goal is to run several independent graphs across several different machines.

As an example, I want to do something like this (assume that the server is open on each machine)

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)
x = tf.mul(a,b)             # To be run on "grpc://www.example0.com:2222"
y = tf.mul(a,b)             # To be run on "grpc://www.example1.com:2222"
z = tf.mul(a,b)             # To be run on "grpc://www.example2.com:2222"

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([x,y,z])       # Ops x,y,z are run on different machines in parallel
```

My current attempt at this is shown in the following code. However, this code runs the sessions in serial, but I want them to be executed in a parallel distributed manner.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)
x = tf.mul(a,b)             # To be run on "grpc://www.example0.com:2222"
y = tf.mul(a,b)             # To be run on "grpc://www.example1.com:2222"
z = tf.mul(a,b)             # To be run on "grpc://www.example2.com:2222"

with tf.Session("grpc://www.example0.com:2222") as sess:
    sess.run(x)
with tf.Session("grpc://www.example1.com:2222") as sess:
    sess.run(y)
with tf.Session("grpc://www.example2.com:2222") as sess:
    sess.run(z)
```

While reading the documentation about Distributed Tensorflow, I found that `tf.device` allows me to set which CPU or GPU to run Tensorflow Ops on. Is there something similar that allows me to set the `session target` to specify which machine will run which op? Or is there another way of distributing Tensorflow Ops?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently struggling with this myself. The following is mostly cribbed from [the tensorflow distributed how-to guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/distributed/index.html).

You can pin ops to a job/task using `tf.device`:

```
clusterspec = \
    { "worker": 
        [ "www.example0.com:2222"
        , "www.example1.com:2222"
        , "www.example2.com:2222"
        ]
    , "master":
        [ "localhost:2222" ]
    }

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)

a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)

# pin 'x' to www.example0.com
with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    x = tf.mul(a, b)

# pin 'y' to www.example1.com
with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
    y = tf.mul(a, b)

server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="master", task_index=0)
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
     # run the ops
     print(sess.run([x, y]))
```

---

<s>However, at least for me, this only works if all the worker processes are on the same machine as the master. Otherwise, it hangs at `sess.run`.</s>

This turned out to be a problem with the use of `localhost` in the cluster specification. If you share the same cluster specification between servers, don't use `localhost`; instead, use the IP address or hostname of the computer that you think `localhost` refers to. In the case of the above example, suppose that you're running the master script on `www.master.com`. You have two options:

#### 1. One clusterspec per server using localhost

On each server, `localhost` refers to the machine running the server.

```
# on www.example0.com
clusterspec = \
    { "worker":
        [ "localhost:2222"
        , "www.example1.com:2222"
        , "www.example2.com:2222"
        ]
    , "master":
        [ "www.master.com:2222" ]
    }

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=0)
server.join()

# on www.example1.com
clusterspec = \
    { "worker":
        [ "www.example0.com:2222"
        , "localhost:2222"
        , "www.example2.com:2222"
        ]
    , "master":
        [ "www.master.com:2222" ]
    }

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=1)
server.join()

# on www.example2.com
clusterspec = \
    { "worker":
        [ "www.example0.com:2222"
        , "www.example1.com:2222"
        , "localhost:2222"
        ]
    , "master":
        [ "www.master.com:2222" ]
    }

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=2)
server.join()

# on www.master.com
clusterspec = \
    { "worker":
        [ "www.example0.com:2222"
        , "www.example1.com:2222"
        , "www.example2.com:2222"
        ]
    , "master":
        [ "localhost:2222" ]
    }

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)

a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    x = tf.mul(a, b)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
    y = tf.mul(a, b)

server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="master", task_index=0)
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
     print(sess.run([x, y]))
```

#### 2. Shared clusterspec

One cluster specification, using IP addresses / domain names that can all be seen from every node.

Saved in `clusterspec.json`:

```
{ "worker":
  [ "www.example0.com:2222"
  , "www.example1.com:2222"
  , "www.example2.com:2222"
  ]
, "master":
  [ "www.master.com:2222" ]
}
```

Then on each worker:

```
import json

with open('clusterspec.json', 'r') as f:
    clusterspec = json.load(f)

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="worker", task_index=<INDEX OF TASK>)
```

Then on the master:

```
import json

with open('clusterspec.json', 'r') as f:
    clusterspec = json.load(f)

cluster = tf.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)

a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    x = tf.mul(a, b)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:1"):
    y = tf.mul(a, b)

server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="master", task_index=0)
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
     print(sess.run([x, y]))
```

Comment: I used the shared cluster spec with hardcoded IPs. Still, when I execute worker.py, I get the following message: Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222

Comment: This happens for all the workers. Consequently, the master hangs at sess.run